# PDFBox not detecting image in page

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm trying to detect images in [this](http://www.filedropper.com/sample_9) pdf using PDFBox. The pdf has two blank images, one on the left side (below the text "Put this IN the box") and the other on the right side (below the text "Affix this OUTSIDE the box"). This is the code I'm using to detect the images:

```
PDPage page = (PDPage) catalog.getAllPages().get(0);
PDStream contents = page.getContents();
PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(contents.getStream());
parser.parse();
List<Object> tokens = parser.getTokens();

PDResources resources = page.getResources();
Map<String, PDXObjectImage> images = resources.getImages();
if(null != images){
        Iterator<String> it = images.keySet().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            String key = it.next();
            System.out.println("Key >>>>>>>>>>>>>> "+key);
        }
}
```

I'm able to detect the second image. However, the first image is not being detected. What is the problem? I'm sure the pdf is proper. I created it multiple times, and still I'm facing the same problem. I created the pdf using Sketch.

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you iterate over all pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In short

> I'm able to detect the second image. However, the first image is not being detected. What is the problem?

Actually *the same image resource is used for both on-page images*, merely stretched to different dimensions.

### In detail

If you look at the content stream of your page, you'll see this at the end:

```
q
720 0 0 970 832 126 cm
/Im1 Do
Q
q
512 0 0 128 144 968 cm
/Im1 Do
Q
```

The first four lines draw the image resource **Im1** at position 832, 126 stretched to 720 x 970, and the last 4 lines draw the same image resource **Im1** at position 144, 968 stretched to 512 x 128.

### What to do

Your approach to merely look at the page resources to find on-page images is inappropriate because

- as you have seen a single image resource may be used multiple times on page stretched to different dimensions,
- an image resource may not be used at all on a page (e.g. some documents have one big resources dictionary referenced from all pages; for a given page many resources may not be used),
- images can be inlined into the content stream; your approach would not see these images at all, and
- form Xobjects or patterns may be displayed on your page which may have images in their own resources respectively; as you only look at image resources contained in the immediate page resources, your approach will not find them either.

A better solution (only failing for inlined and probably patterned images) is presented in the PDFBox sample [`PrintImageLocations`](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/tags/1.8.9/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/PrintImageLocations.java) the output of which for your file is

```
*******************************************************************
Found image [Im1]
position = 832.0, 128.0
size = 360px, 462px
size = 720.0, 970.0
size = 10.0in, 13.472222in
size = 254.0mm, 342.19446mm

*******************************************************************
Found image [Im1]
position = 144.0, 128.0
size = 360px, 462px
size = 512.0, 128.0
size = 7.111111in, 1.7777778in
size = 180.62222mm, 45.155556mm
```

This sample makes use of the PDFBox [`PDFStreamEngine`](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/tags/1.8.9/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFStreamEngine.java) to parse the content processed to draw a page.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Quick question. I assume the processOperator() method is being called by the PDFStreamEngine's processStream() method. So is there any way to pass additional parameters to the processOperator() method? I want to pass a byte[] to it so that I can use the byte[] within the method.

Comment: I want to pass a byte[] so that I can replace the images with the byte[].

Comment: If I were you I would try to not change the PDFBox API like that because **A** you'd have to introduce the change again and again whenever you update the PDFBox version you use; **B** Other code in your project using PDFBox might expect the original API and hiccup due to your change. **C** Such kind of information does not really belong there, keep information and concerns in the program layer it belongs. **D** The `PDFStreamEngine` and classes derived from it are not really targeted at *changing* the content but merely to **analyze* it.

Comment: So how would I replace the image? The only way I'm able to detect both the images are inside the processOperator() method. Or should I just implement the same method myself? Not sure if that is the right way.

Comment: Image replacement comes at different degrees of difficulty. The easiest way is to merely replace an image resourse. That doesn't suffice in your case as the same resource is used twice. Thus, you will have to edit the content stream. In your specific case editing of the page content stream suffices (in some cases other object's content streams also have to be taken into account). Are you looking for a generic solution or a solution specific to your one PDF?

Comment: Just specific to the pdf.

Comment: In your simple case you can add the replacement image to the page resources using a new name, read the page content stream using a `PDFStreamParser`, retrieve the tokens from it, replace the name parameter of the rarget **Do** operation with the new name, serialize the changed content using a `ContentStreamWriter`, and update the page to use the new stream as content stream. For the use of the mentioned classes, cf. the example [ReplaceString.java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/tags/1.8.9/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/ReplaceString.java).

Comment: The problem is, I have to replace both the blank images with 2 separate images. However, if I replace one, the other one is replaced with the same image as well since both the blank images are from the same image resource. I tried overriding the processOperator() method and replaced the images inside based on the imageHeight from the PrintImageLocation example you provided earlier. However, it still ends up replacing both the images with the same image. I'm new to PDFBox, so I might be doing it wrong.

Comment: Please make this a question in its own right. This question here is about *detecting* the images, so my answer above also is, and the comments here are too small to clear up everything. Create a new question about *replacing* the images with different new images.

Comment: I have asked a separate question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31009949/replacing-images-with-same-resource-in-pdfbox

Comment: I'll look into that tomorrow.

Comment: @drunkenfist Does my implementation of Tilman's idea in my answer to that other question serve your purpose?