# PDF generated using PDFBox is magnified when printing / saving via Safari

Tags: pdf, safari, pdfbox

I generated a pdf using PDFBox which is then sent to the front-end. When I print / save this pdf in Chrome / Firefox, it looks good. However, when I try to do the same using Safari, the pdf is magnified.

Not sure if this is a browser issue or whether it has something to do with Safari not able to read the pdf properly. Any ideas?

[This](http://www.filedropper.com/chromesample) is the pdf generated from Chrome, and [this](http://www.filedropper.com/safarisample) is the one from Safari (I've redacted few details).

This is my code:

```
PDXObjectImage blankImg = (PDXObjectImage) object;
if(blankImg.getHeight() > 460){         
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(shippingLabel));

BufferedImage resizedImage = Scalr.resize(img, Scalr.Method.BALANCED, Scalr.Mode.FIT_EXACT, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());

// Convert images to jpg format
BufferedImage jpegImage = new BufferedImage(resizedImage.getWidth(),resizedImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
jpegImage.createGraphics().drawImage(resizedImage, 0, 0, Color.WHITE, null);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();                       
ImageIO.write(jpegImage, "jpg", baos);                      

// Replace empty image in template with the image generated from shipping label byte array
PDXObjectImage carrierLabel = new PDJpeg(doc, new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));
blankImg.getCOSStream().replaceWithStream(carrierLabel.getCOSStream());
break;
}

PDStream updatedStream = new PDStream(doc);
OutputStream out = updatedStream.createOutputStream();
ContentStreamWriter tokenWriter = new ContentStreamWriter(out);
tokenWriter.writeTokens(tokens);
page.setContents(updatedStream);

// Convert PDDoc to byte[]
ByteArrayOutputStream outUpdated = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
doc.save(outUpdated);
return outUpdated.toByteArray();
```

This is what I'm doing. I have a pdf with a blank image. I read this image, and replace this with another existing image which is available as byte array, and finally return the updated pdf as a byte array as ResponseEntity from Spring boot server running in the backend.

Thanks.

Comment: You should share the PDF.

Comment: ... And the central code fragments of your Pdfbox usage.

Comment: I have added the code / pdf. Any suggestions?

Comment: *This is the pdf generated from Safari, and this is the one from Chrome* - File dropper seems to not know your URLs.

Comment: @mkl Sorry, looks like the link had expired. I've uploaded them again.

Comment: At first glance it looks like a Safari issue. I'll look set it later.

Comment: Ok, eventually I could look at your files on a regular computer, not a smart phone. It turned out that the PDFs you provided unfortunately cannot be used for analysis, they each only contain a single image. I don't know whether this is due to your way of *printing / saving* or of the way you *have redacted few details*.

Comment: Furthermore the source you provide does not suffice for analysis either because several variables appear out of thin air, e.g. `tokens`. Depending on the contents of these variables your result may or may not validly represent what you want. I merely can tell that you seem to not have chosen the solution from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31018974/1729265) for injecting the final images into your PDF.

Comment: For analysis, therefore, we would need the actual PDF generated by your code, i.e. the contents of `outUpdated.toByteArray()`. *Please do **not** redact* the file because redaction may change the internals of a file considerably. If certain details may not be public, use fake `shippingLabel` images in your code instead.